# Creating multiple sites with Drupal on LAMP/WAMP

Tags: drupal, wamp, lamp

I am confused as to how I can use Drupal to create multiple sites for a WAMP or LAMP installation.

I currently have everything setup and Drupal setup in the following directories:

/var/www/drupal-7.12
c:/wamp/www/drupal-7.12

When I access these folders from the browser I am able to modify and create content for my webpage.

It would appear to me that the default Drupal folder is the only one I can create my website in.

My question is: if I have multiple sites that I need to create with this one Drupal installation, how can I achieve it?

For example:

c:/wamp/www/mysite1
c:/wamp/www/mysite2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document will explain a bit on how to run multiple sites from the same code base http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site.

If your sites will share some common elements like users, this might also be helpful: http://drupal.org/node/201673

Answer (score 0):

There may be more documentation written on the subject at Drupal.org, but most of what I can tell can be found in the following files. Be sure to read the comments in these files.

[Drupal Root Directory]/sites/example.sites.php

and

[Drupal Root Directory]/sites/default/default.settings.php

In general, the way Drupal 6 worked is that you needed to create subdirectories for each of your sites in the the sites directory. So that you would have a directory structure that looks like:

- sites/default
- sites/example-1.com
- sites/example-2.com
- etc.

I would imagine that D7 keeps this same structure, but I haven't yet It looks like the sites.php file provides a mapping of domain names and site directories that you can use to map. Drupal, will default to sites/default if it can't find an appropriate match.

While it's targeted toward linux, this might be a good place to find multisite info as well:
http://drupal.org/node/1114158